# Decoding a base64 encoded image produces flat array

Tags: python, numpy, base64

I am trying to send images to algorithmia server by encoding an image to base64. But when I use base64 module to decode it, it produces 1d array which can not be used as a image .

```
img = cv2.imread("/home/abdullah/Desktop/Profile.png")
img = cv2.resize(img, (512, 512))
encoded_string = base64.b64encode(img)
img1 = base64.decodestring(encoded_string)
print(img1)
```

Actual result should be like the original image :

```
[[[ 87 129 255][ 88 128 255][ 90 130 255]...[ 54  80 174]
```

But after decoding result is :

```
[ 87 129 255 ...  51 100 156]
```

Please help me !

Comment: b64encode() takes in a byte string. Could you do a print(img) to see what is being fed to b64encode()?

Comment: Yes, it is [[[ 87 129 255]
  [ 88 128 255]
  [ 90 130 255]
  ...
  [ 54  80 174]
  [ 52  82 174]
  [ 54  77 168]]

 [[ 86 117 255]

Answer (score 0):

After, trying lots of solution I finally got the solution.

```
encoded_string = base64.b64encode(img)
img1 = base64.decodestring(encoded_string)
q = np.frombuffer(img1, dtype=np.uint8)  # Because image was in uint8
q = np.array(q)
q = q.reshape(512, 512,3)
plt.imshow(q)
plt.show()
```